# Find and replace Heading tags with regex in Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

There's a OCR scanned book and there's a tool which converts the OCR'd PDF to XML but most of the XML tags are wrong so there's another tool to fix it. But I need to break the lines from `<h1>` to `<h5>`, 1. & 1.1. & 1.1.1. so its easy to re-tag using the tool.

The XML code looks like this:

```
`<h1>text</h1><h2>text</h3><h3>text</h3>"
```

and

```
1.text.2.text.3.text.1.1.text.1.1.1.text
```

And I need to break the lines like this using a Regex in notepad++.

```
<h1>text</h1>
<h2>text</h2>
<h3>text</h3>
```

and

```
1.text.
2.text.
3.text.
```

and

```
1.1.text.
1.1.1.text.
```

I used `</h1>\s*` to find an `</h1>\n` but it only breaks `h1` tags. I need to break all "H" tags and 1., 2., 1.1., 1.1.1. tags too.

Comment: Please show the `Find` and `Replace` strings you have tried.

Comment: Could you edit your question to give it a correct formatting.

Comment: you have mentioned two type for inputs/output. Not clear to me. Simply written actual input and expected ouput.

Comment: @user3697139 So you want to replace every occurrence of `<h1>text</h1>` with `n.text.` where `n` increases each time? And replace every occurrence of `<h2>text</h2>` with `n.m.text.` where `n` follows the preceding `h1` tag and `m` increases each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this search and replace *(if your h1, h2, ... tags don't contain other tags)*:

```
search:  (?<!^)(<h[1-6][^<]*|(?<![0-9]\.)[0-9]+\.)
replace: \n$1
```

note: if you need Windows newlines, you must change `\n` with `\r\n`.

pattern details:

```
(?<!^)   # not preceded by the begining of the string

(                         # open the capture group 1
    <h[1-6][^<]*          # <h, a digit between 1 to 6, all characters until 
                          # the next < (to skip all the content between
                          # h1, h2... tags) 
  |                     # OR
    (?<![0-9]\.)[0-9]+\.  # one or more digits and a dot not preceded by a digit
                          # and a dot 
)                         # close the capture group 1
```

`$1` is a reference to the content of the capture group 1

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of getting downvoted, i think you may be better served by a parser. In the past when I've had to manage similar tasks, I would write a small script/program to parse the file and re-write it as needed. Parsing the xml first, and then reformatting using regex might be easier to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Notepad++'s regex is up to the task, and without too much complexity, but only once the question is clear.

Comment: jeez i'm so embarrassed .that i don't know how to post the question in plain text.